# i tried to add relevant tags but couldn't

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have a question about my Seasoned Advice post: [hard navy beans- will this soften them?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/124750/hard-navy-beans-will-this-soften-them)

why are we not allowed to add relevant tags? several times i tried to add  the tags needed for this post .   however for some unreasonable reason, i can't  add them so  anyone coul d find it by searching for the  issue keywords. Can't even  use "navy "  or "hard", or skin,  that's so ridiculous . Please someone add them!  also,  cooking and boiling, cooked, boiled. They won't let me use those either. only " beans". that's not gonna help very much! can't get  specific.

Answer (score 5):

We have a system where functionality is unlocked by users stepwise, depending on their reputation. This is because new users don't usually know how the tools are supposed to be used. Creating new tags [is available at 300 reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), that's 30 upvotes to posts you have written.

Your question here demonstrates very well the need for such a system. Your new proposed tags aren't useful, and should not exist.

- **navy** is a word which pretty much only appears in cooking in the phrase "navy beans". I can't think of a cooking question which applies to navy beans and not to any other kind of beans.
- **hard** is a quite random descriptor. The set of all our questions that refer to hard foods would be a motley collection, without any coherence. The same goes for **skin**. We don't need to combine questions about hard bean skins, discolored apple skins and crispy chicken skin.
- **cooking** or versions like **cooked** are tags which are blacklisted on our site, such that not even users with the creation privilege can create them. We are a site about cooking, if we had this tag, all questions on the site should have it.
- **boiling** already exists as a tag.

The tag "beans" seems already like a good descriptor of your question, I don't see a need to add more tags anyway. If you really want to, you can add "texture", that one should already exist.